# How to show Department for Person in Share Point Lists?

Tags: list

I have a custom-built project requirement list in which I need to store Person's name and Department id (both from outlook contacts property).

What I want to do is when user fills in details in Person column, I want to propose department name (of course, user will have the possibility to change this value).

I am not sure if this is possible, but in the column property, one can set default value.  The default value can be a Caluculated Value which can be generated thru formula. Can some one help me with a formulat where in from the person's name, I show his department.

Thanks in advance.
Madhu

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there is no formula to look up information from the users account details.
This would require a custom field to make and LDAP or SharePoint profile lookup.